# how to select only empty (or false) values in tabulator.js

Tags: tabulator

How can I only filter the null (or false) values in tabulator.js (V4.9)
This is my column definition:

```
{ title: "Lead", field: "delivered", width: 25, hozAlign: "center", formatter: "tickCross", formatterParams: { allowEmpty: true }, headerSort: false, editable: true, editor: "tick", headerFilter: true },
```

It is actually filtering either the true values or not filtering at all (ie. removing the filter).
I'm actually looking to get a 3 state filter (true, false, empty) ie. selecting either the delivered==true or delivered==false or remove all filter)
Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tickCross header filter already supports tristate opperation, you simply need to add the `tristate` option to its `headerFilterParams`:

```js
{ title:"Lead", field:"delivered", headerFilter:"tickCross", headerFilterParams:{tristate:true}},
```

Comment: Well, it actually only works if there is no editable: true,  editor: "tick" defined for that column. If so, than it selects only the true values or all.Is it a bug?

Comment: The editors are completely seperate from header filters when they are running and won't effect eachother. Can you create a JS fiddle or code pen that demonstrates your issue. It is very hard to offer advice without seeing how your whole table is setup

Comment: Sure. https://jsfiddle.net/h0svkfoy/  As you can see you can correctly filter the KP column which is read only but not the 3 Állapot fields where the only difference I see are the fact they are editable

Comment: This issue is because you are using `headerFilter:true`, in your case it should be `headerFilter: "tickCross"`. That will resolve your issue

Comment: Thank you, Oli. It works now. :-) I just don't understand why it was working for my KP column but not for the others, but never mind. Great job anyway!